# Drupal get form returns string "array"

Tags: 7, forms

I have module, that should build form. However it is not showing form.

There is my code:

```
function weblabs_form() {
    $form = array();

$form['name']=array(
    '#type'=>'textfield',
    '#title'=>t('Enter your name'),
    '#description'=>t('Your first name goes here')
);
$form['last_name']=array(
    '#type'=>'textfield',
    '#title'=>t('Enter your Last name'),
    '#description'=>t('Your Last name goes here')
);

$form['email']=array(
    '#type'=>'textfield',
    '#title'=>t('Enter your email'),
    '#description'=>t('Your email goes here')
);

$form['country']=array(
    '#type'=>'select',


       '#title'=>t('Select your country'),
        '#options'=>array('USA','UK','France','Japan')
    );

    $form['submit']=array(
        '#type'=>'submit',
        '#value'=>t('Submit')
    );

    return $form;
}

function weblabs_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
    echo("<h1>TEST</h1>");
    drupal_set_message("TEST");
}

function weblabs_menu() {
    $items['calculator'] = array(
        'title' => 'Kalkulačka WebLabs',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('weblabs_form'),
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        );
    return $items;
}`
```

Answer (score 2):

To print the HTML code corresponding to your form you need to render it:

```
$form = drupal_get_form('weblabs_form');
print drupal_render($form);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the name (id) of your form is not the most appropriate : weblabs_form reference the [hook_form hook](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_form/7.x), with is used to add custom form elements to be displayed in the node editing form.

Consider changing its name (and the submit method associate) with something less ambivalent (example: calculator_page and calculator_page_submit).

The [drupal_get_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7.x) method returns a Form API array for a given form ID. You must use the [drupal_render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_render/7.x) method to render it properly...
See https://www.drupal.org/node/224333#unrendered.

After, the MENU_CALLBACK option do not generate a menu, but you must be able to access your form on /calculator on your drupal website. The drupal_render method is directly call from the template (normally).

Answer (score 0):

In addition, if you want to have a form page. You should use `drupal_get_form` as the page call function and the form builder name as the arguments

```php
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['path/to/form'] = array(
    'title' => 'Weblabs Form',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('weblabs_form'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  return $items;
}
```